# Mitmproxy - docker - SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: docker, mitmproxy

I'm using mitmproxy docker container
https://hub.docker.com/r/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/

I'm executing the container using this command:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8080:8080 mitmproxy/mitmproxy
```

I'm struglying to undenstand how to execute this command from the container:

```
SSLKEYLOGFILE=$HOME/.mitmproxy/sslkeylogfile.txt mitmproxy
```

I need to collect SSLKEYLOG file for wireshark inspection.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own Dockerfile and run that.

```
FROM mitmproxy/mitmproxy:5.0.1
ENV SSLKEYLOGFILE=/sslkeylogfile.txt mitmproxy

ENTRYPOINT ["mitmdump","-flow-detail 0"]
```